# jQuery Star Rating Selected Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm working the the jQuery Star Rating system that converts a drop down box into five stars, etc. It work okay but I just cannot get it to hold a preselected value when the page loads. It always loads with nothing selected.

Here is my select in test.html:

```
<select name="rating" class="rating">
     <option value="1">Very poor</option>
     <option selected value="2">Not Bad</option>
     <option value="3">Average</option>
     <option value="4">Good</option>
     <option value="5">Perfect</option>
</select>
```

And my jQuery in test.html:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".rating").rating();
});
```

And a section that should do what I need from jquery.rating.js

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.rating = function(options)
{

    var settings =
    {
       showCancel: true,
       cancelValue: null,
       cancelTitle: "Cancel",
       startValue: null,
       disabled: false
    };
```

Now according to the documentation, if startValue is NULL I should be able to use the selected="selected" option in my drop down, that didn't work so I set startValue equal to 2 and then when that didn't I tried "Not Bad" and still nothing. However, if I go and change disabled in the .js file to false, it locks out the star rating just as it should. I'm stumped, anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try like:

```
$('.rating > option[value=2]').attr('selected', true);
```

Above will set option with value `2` to be selected. You need to adjust `2` above for whatever option you want to make selected in your drop down.

Comment: Unfortunately, that still didn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late to the game, but just in case you're still having this problem, or someone else runs into this question and needs an answer... this should work.

After this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".rating").rating();
    ...
```

Try this:

```
    ...
    $(".rating").val(2).change();
```

According to the docs, you have to specifically call ".change()" if you want to manually set the value. I do this in one of my own sites. To be honest, I don't regard this plugin very highly, but sometimes you don't have a choice :-/